# Check simultaneously pickerview value swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uipickerview, xcode8

Hi guys i've a problem i would like to check simultaneously the values of my 4 pickerView and change the text of a label that is connected `@IBOutlet var numeroSpire: UILabel!`

This is my didSelectRow method

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var elementoSelezionato: Int = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    var filoSelezionato: String = DataManager.shared.storageFili[elementoSelezionato].nome
    var sizeSelezionato: String = DataManager.shared.storageSize[elementoSelezionato].grandezzaFilo
    var diametroSelezionato: String = DataManager.shared.storageDiametro[elementoSelezionato].diametroResistenza
    var ohmSelezionato: String = DataManager.shared.storageOhm[elementoSelezionato].ohmResistenza

    if filoSelezionato == "Filo0" && sizeSelezionato == "Grandezza2" && diametroSelezionato == "Ohm2" && ohmSelezionato == "Diametro2" {

        numeroSpire.text = "8 Spire"

    } else {
        numeroSpire.text = "Completa la selezione"
    }

}
```

But if i run the application on iPhone simulator and i choose the value i wrote in the code doesn't work, the label change with "Completa la selezione" even if the value are the same of my code.
Can anyone help me??

EDIT: code of DataManager

```
class DataManager: NSObject {

static let shared = DataManager()

var storageFili :  [FiliModel] = []
var storageSize :  [FiloSizeModel] = []
var storageOhm :  [OhmResistenzaModel] = []
var storageDiametro :  [DiametroResistenza] = []

func creaDatiFili() {
    let nichelCromo = FiliModel(nome: "Filo0")
    let ni200 = FiliModel(nome: "Filo1")
    let ss = FiliModel(nome: "Filo2")

    storageFili = [nichelCromo, ni200, ss]
}

func creaDatiSize() {
    let size006 = FiloSizeModel(grandezzaFilo: "Grandezza0")
    let size007 = FiloSizeModel(grandezzaFilo: "Grandezza1")
    let size008 = FiloSizeModel(grandezzaFilo: "Grandezza2")

    storageSize = [size006, size007, size008]
}

func creaDatiOhm() {
    let ohm006 = OhmResistenzaModel(ohmResistenza: "Ohm0")
    let ohm007 = OhmResistenzaModel(ohmResistenza: "Ohm1")
    let ohm008 = OhmResistenzaModel(ohmResistenza: "Ohm2")

    storageOhm = [ohm006, ohm007, ohm008]
}

func creaDatiDiametro() {

    let diam30 = DiametroResistenza(diametroResistenza: "Diametro0")
    let diam35 = DiametroResistenza(diametroResistenza: "Diametro1")
    let diam20 = DiametroResistenza(diametroResistenza: "Diametro2")

    storageDiametro = [diam30, diam35, diam20]
}
```

}

Comment: Can u show the value assigned to all 4 variables. I am assuming all 4 variables not equal to  their compare  constants.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Can u print value assigned to all 4 variables in didSelectRow ?